# not enought free disk space

Tags: software-installation

I'm a total beginner with Ubuntu and every time I got this message. Please how can I solve it? What do they mean with the message `free space on disk '/boot'` and how can I fix it?

Comment: You forgot to provide a link to the image.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for that but I have already got and answer=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clean up all the unused kernel packages, type in Terminal: 
`sudo apt-get autoremove`

---

Another easier way, is to install the `ubuntu-tweak` tool, it can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/tualatrix/ubuntu-tweak). Go to "Janitor", and select "Old Kernel" to clean.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think is works. May I ask you another question please. I installed Ubuntu 15 in  my computer and remove windows from it and now I want to install it back but I dont know how to do it. This because I started to study programming 1C# and this program (visual studio community) works only with windows. Thanks in advance. Clod

Comment: You can easily install windows under [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads). Please Mark my answer as the correct